# Best way to minimise a jQuery statement

Tags: jquery

I have two forms which I am currently switching out with an onChange event dependent on which options value has been selected.

My current code is working but I want to learn the best way to reduce these two statements by combining them. What would be the most effective method?

```js
$('#selectSearchPages').change(function() {
  if ($('#selectSearchPages').val() == 'pages') {
    $('.searchFormProducts').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages').show();
    $('.pageSearch').show();
    $('.productSearch').hide();
  } else {
    $('.searchFormProducts').show();
    $('.searchFormPages').hide();
    $('.pageSearch').hide();
    $('.productSearch').show();
  }
});

$('#selectSearchProducts').change(function() {
  if ($('#selectSearchProducts').val() == 'products') {
    $('.searchFormProducts').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages').show();
    $('.pageSearch').hide();
    $('.productSearch').show();
  } else {
    $('.searchFormProducts').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages').show();
    $('.pageSearch').show();
    $('.productSearch').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='searchFormWrap searchFormPages'>
  <div class='mobselect'>
    <p class='smp med noMar'>Search again pages:</p>
    <select name='selectSearchForm' id='selectSearchPagesMob' class='show-for-small-only'>
      <option name='pages' value='pages'>Pages</option>
      <option name='products' value='products'>Products</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="{{site.link}}">
    <input type="text" value="{{ fn('get_search_query') }}" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Enter your keywords here..." />
    <select name='selectSearchForm' id='selectSearchPages' class='hide-for-small-only'>
      <option name='pages' value='pages'>Pages</option>
      <option name='products' value='products'>Products</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit' class="blueB">Search</button>
  </form>
  <p class='smp med noMar center'>You searched for <span class="pageSearch">pages</span><span class="productSearch">products</span>.
    <p class='smp med noMar center'>To search <span class="productSearch">products</span><span class="pageSearch">pages</span>, select from the drop down above and enter your search.</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include all relevant HTML in the question

Comment: Just added, the other form is the same with different classes.

Comment: I think this is fine. Combining them will require more complicated if/then code.

Comment: I want the least amount of code possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the script by simplifying the classes used. You have to many different classes that are too specific. You need only two: `.pages` and `.products`.

Use those classes on the element that should display when the `select` value is that class.

So that could be as simple as:

```
$("select.pagesOrProducts").change(function() {

  // A boolean true/false
  let display = $(this).val() == "products"
  
  $('.products').toggle(display);
  $('.pages').toggle(!display);  // Notice the exclamation mark here
});
```

`.toggle(true)` is the same as `.show()` and `.toggle(false)` is the same as `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple elements `$('.searchFormProducts, .productSearch')`

https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

```js
$('#selectSearchPages').change(function() {
  if ($('#selectSearchPages').val() == 'pages') {
    $('.searchFormProducts, .productSearch').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages, .pageSearch').show();
  } else {
    $('.searchFormProducts, .productSearch').show();
    $('.searchFormPages, .pageSearch').hide();
  }
});

$('#selectSearchProducts').change(function() {
  if ($('#selectSearchProducts').val() == 'products') {
    $('.searchFormProducts, .pageSearch').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages, .productSearch').show();
  } else {
    $('.searchFormProducts, .productSearch').hide();
    $('.searchFormPages, .pageSearch').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='searchFormWrap searchFormPages'>
  <div class='mobselect'>
    <p class='smp med noMar'>Search again pages:</p>
    <select name='selectSearchForm' id='selectSearchPagesMob' class='show-for-small-only'>
      <option name='pages' value='pages'>Pages</option>
      <option name='products' value='products'>Products</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="{{site.link}}">
    <input type="text" value="{{ fn('get_search_query') }}" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Enter your keywords here..." />
    <select name='selectSearchForm' id='selectSearchPages' class='hide-for-small-only'>
      <option name='pages' value='pages'>Pages</option>
      <option name='products' value='products'>Products</option>
    </select>
    <button type='submit' class="blueB">Search</button>
  </form>
  <p class='smp med noMar center'>You searched for <span class="pageSearch">pages</span><span class="productSearch">products</span>.
    <p class='smp med noMar center'>To search <span class="productSearch">products</span><span class="pageSearch">pages</span>, select from the drop down above and enter your search.</span>.
</div>
```